# Dynamically setting Facebook social sharing main thumbnail

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with a list of items and each has an Addthis share button, I wanted the 1st Facebook thumbnail in teh sharer to be that of the item selected, so I tried many solutions which didn't work, and finally I tried to dynamically write and read from SQL the URL to the thumbnail for **og:image** and **rel="image_src"** each time a user clicks the share button to the particular item, this way the Facebook scraper has the details to the selected item at parse-time, but yet it doesn't seem to work, the thumbnail is not even shown among the thumbnail options.

Is there a reliable way to set the main thumbnail when such a page has more than 1 share button?

[image]

Comment: The url shared by those buttons it's always the same? Or each button shares a different url?

Comment: It's always different, each has it's own URL and page, but that is fixed, I've made it show correct URL in the FB sharer, but still the wrong thumbnail, usually a random one.

Answer (score 0):

ShareThis offers the option to select the thumbnail image using the **st_image** tag, here you can find more info. So basically I had to switch from Addthis to ShareThis.